# Httr for HTTP API POST

Tags: r, httr

I am trying to and information from an HTTP protocol that looks like the code below (modified because it is using a private API).

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http:// http://sdts.org /soap/envelope/"  xmlns:tem="http://sdts.org/" xmlns:jump="http://sdts.org/2004/07/Contracts">    <soapenv:Header/>   <soapenv:Body>
          <tem:GetCabs>
             <tem:request>
                <jump:BoardFort>BOB</jump:BoardFort>
                <jump: ZortCode>VS</jump:ZortCode>
                <jump:ClassInformation>
                   <jump:SamenessClassCabs>
                      <jump:SamenessClass>Y</jump:SamenessClass>
                   </jump:SamenessClassCabs>
                </jump:ClassInformation>
                <jump:RunDate>2015-12-01T00:00:00+00:00</jump:DepartureDate>
                <jump:Equipment>346</jump:Equipment>
                <jump:CoronorNumber>45</jump:CoronorNumber>
                <jump:OffFort>SSS</jump:OffFort>
                <jump:LobbyDate>2015-11-25T00:00:00</jump:LobbyDate>
             </tem:request>
          </tem:GetCabs>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am using this code and I get a 415 error:

```
library(httr)
install.packages("httr")
library(httr)
classURL<- "http://sssdddd.com:10004/DataService/http"
Cabin<-POST(url = classURL,
           body = list(BoardFort = "BOB",
                        ZortCode = "88",
                        ClassInformation = NULL,
                        SamenessClassCabs = NULL,
                        SamenessClass = "Y",
                        SamenessClassCabs = NULL,
                        ClassInformation = NULL,
                        RunDate = "2015-11-25T00:00:00",
                        CoronorNumber = "45",
                        OffFort = "SSS",
                        LobbyDate = "2015-11-25T00:00:00"))
```

This might be because of the nesting in the code. How is that handled in httr? Any suggestions? Or am I missing something else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last datetime needs quotes around it, and `jump:SamenessClassCabs` needs to be wrapped in quotes or backticks so the `:` doesn't get evaluated.

Comment: I did that and it did not make a difference.

Comment: `httr` isn't going to do the XML encoding for you and SOAP requests require XML to be in the body of the call. You have to build the XML data structure in R either with something like `whisker` templates, `sprintf` or `XML`. I'm so sorry you have to work with SOAP. The folks who thought that up will prbly never get their karma back.